# Does CSS Media Queries work locally?

Tags: resolution, media-queries, css

I was looking for my answer @ [CSS media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) but couldn't find it so I thought I would ask here.

Can CSS media queries be used offline/locally? I'm building a webpage it's all on shared network drives and I'm trying to setup different stylesheets based on resolution and I want to use CSS media queries `min-width` but they don't seem to be working and I'm wondering if it's because my site isn't live? (similar to how favicon doesn't work locally, only on hosted sites).

An example would be:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        @media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
            background-image: url(images/bigbg.jpeg);
        }
        body {
            width: 1000px;
            background-image:url('images/test.PNG');
            background-repeat:repeat;
            overflow-x:scroll;
        }
    </style>
```

Any suggestions? Much appreciated :)

Comment: Try moving the media queries after the normal CSS.

Comment: The Media Queries are processed by the browser, and have no dependency on whether the browser got the files via http:, ftp:, file:, or something else. It's common for Media Queries to not work like you think they should though. Get familiar with your browser's "error console". And maybe it would help to point your browser at a diagnostic like http://www.ckollars.org/dimensions-no-meta-viewport.html and http://www.ckollars.org/dimensions-meta-viewport.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work locally, but you need to define what's changing. Try:

Original:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1024px) {
        body {background-image: url(images/bigbg.jpeg);}
}
```

Even better:

```
@media all and (min-width:1024px){
        body{background:url(images/bigbg.jpg)}
}
```